# Resize tall images to the size of other images in flexbox grid

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, grid, flexbox

So I have a flexbox grid on a Wordpress category page displaying all my posts with title and excerpt.  Most images are the same proportions except a few which are much taller.  I want to set the max-height of the tall images to the height of the regular images responsively.  Each item in the grid has an image container with the class of imageThumb.

```
(function($) {
 $('.imageThumb img').each(function() {
    var maxHeight;
    var width = $(this).clientWidth;    // Current image width
    var height = $(this).clientHeight;  // Current image height

    // Check if the current width is larger than the max
    if(width > height){
        maxHeight = $(this).clientHeight;
        console.log(maxHeight)
    }

    // Check if current height is larger than max
    if(height > width){
        $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

I know I am returning too many heights with the (width > height) bit. I can't highlight specific images and get their heights because the content is always changing and shifting on this blog.

Here is my css that pertains to this.

```
.imageThumb {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imageThumb img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I don't want to set a width and height for the image (my original solution) because the site owner wants the pics to keep on scaling up as the window size gets bigger).  I also tried setting the image as absolutely positioned and fitting it within a container but that didn't seem to work for this situation. Not sure what the best course of action is for this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I belived to got your problem but I have a doubt.. why you check the width it's not enought to set all the image with the same height ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but I think you're saying why don't I set all the images to a certain height? I could but it seems excessive when all I need to do is set a max-height for the tall ones.

Comment: sure that was my meaning check the code

Answer (score 1):

Hi I don't know if I understood well, if not please let me see your link.

By the way I think that this code should to make the job

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$('.imageThumb img').each(function(){
   var thisH = $(this).height();
   if (thisH > maxHeight) { maxHeight = thisH; }
});

$('.imageThumb img').height(maxHeight);
```

cheers!!

Comment: This led me to the right path.  Pasting the correct code below. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Daebak Do led me to the correct answer with some mods. I needed to set the max height of the container imageThumb so that the width stayed the same as the other pics without warping the tall pic.  If it ends up cutting off too much of your pic you can try the commented code.

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$('.imageThumb').each(function(){
   var thisH = $(this).height();
   if (thisH > maxHeight) { 
    maxHeight = thisH;
    $('.imageThumb').css('maxHeight', maxHeight);
    //may need to change to the following if pics are getting cut off too much
    // $('.imageThumb img').css('maxHeight', maxHeight);
    // // $('.imageThumb img').css('width', 'auto');

     }
});
```

The above code wasn't working for everything I needed to do so see the below code as well.  Feedback welcome!

```
var imageThumb = document.getElementsByClassName('imageThumb');
var arr=[];
var tallArr=[];
//add all items to an array
$(".imageThumb").each(function(){ arr.push($(this));});
//filter out all items that are taller than they are wide
arr.filter(function(obj){
  if(obj.context.clientHeight > obj.context.clientWidth) {
    tallArr.push(obj);
  } 
});


//loop through the items that are tall and add a new class to them
for (i = 0; i <= tallArr.length; i++) {
  $(tallArr[i]).addClass('bigHeight'); 
}
//gets first item that has a normal height and grabs it's height value
var normalHeight = arr[0].context.clientHeight;
//change css of bigHeight

//sets bigHeight equal to normalHeight
$('.bigHeight').css('max-height', normalHeight);
```